# SKAction.removeFromParent do not remove a sprite with SKAction.repeatActionForever

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

The The method .removeFromParent() does not remove the sprite. What's wrong?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard touches.first != nil else  {
        return
    }

    let myShot = SKSpriteNode()
    let myShotAnimation = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(myShotTexture, timePerFrame: 0.01))
    myShot.size = CGSizeMake(200, 200)
    myShot.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    myShot.zPosition = 0
    sprite!.addChild(myShot)
    let myShotAction = SKAction.group([SKAction.scaleBy(0.1, duration: 0.5), myShotAnimation])
    let actionRemove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    myShot.runAction (SKAction.sequence([myShotAction, actionRemove]))

}
```

The sprite "myShot" with animation does not disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Madhouse. I replaced the action

```
 SKAction.repeatActionForever
```

per action

```
SKAction.repeatAction
```

and everything worked.

Comment: When you say that it worked with `SKAction.repeatAction`, I assume that you've meant `SKAction.repeatAction: count` which have a definite duration, means it will finish at some point. That is why `actionRemove` is called. Look at @AlessandroOrnano's answer. He described the problem correctly.

Comment: Thank you. He guessed five hours.

Comment: Please do not expand your question in an answer. If you have found the answer, you can post it and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @CloakedEddy - I wrote his decision 5 hours before the first answer. Look at the time of publication.

Answer (score 3):

Simply because `actionRemove` will never be called.

When you launch:

```
myShot.runAction (SKAction.sequence([myShotAction, actionRemove]))
```

sequentially running the `myShotAction` SKAction and , when it's finished, the `actionRemove`. But if the first SKAction is an action thats never ends (*SKAction.repeatActionForever*), the `actionRemove` will never called.

Comment: Hi Alessandro , having the same issue, do you think I should revert the repeatactionforever and have it as repeat(action, count) instead?

Comment: Instead of your idea, you could try to make 2 runaction, the first with only repeatActionForEver, the second with a sequence with a wait delay and your action.